# unit-root test for unbalanced multivariate panel data

Tags: r, panel-data, unit-root

I want to conduct unit root test for my unbalanced multi-variate panel data. I use only R studio. I saw many helpful posts on Stata and EViews but I am seeking solutions for RStudio only, please. I searched on the internet how to conduct the test but I haven't been able to find a successful solution.

I saw that for purtest(..., test="hadri") (of package plm) and others are not suitable for unbalanced panel data. In one of the posts, I saw that the Fisher-type test is applicable to the unbalanced test but I'm not sure how to write codes for the Fisher-type unit root test. I also saw posts on how to balance panel data from unbalanced ones to carry out tests but in my case, I don't think that's what I need.

Any code examples would be appreciated.

Comment: crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66940398/unit-root-test-for-unbalanced-panel-data